# How to remove app with the previous version when I install a new version

Tags: iphone, ios, implicit, reinstall

the previous version of the app has some implicit with the newest version, and if users install the new version, maybe the app will be crashed, so is there any way to remove the previous version when I install the new version, thanks~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly force this. You can ask your customers to uninstall the app first, but it is much better to ensure that your newer version correctly cleans up anything left over from older versions.

Comment: ok~ thanks may be I should post a declaration for all users~ :(

Answer (score 2):

The app bundle — what is installed by iTunes — is replaced entirely when you upgrade it.  None of your old code remains.  The only bits that can remain from previous installations are data: items you have created in your application documents directory; key-value pairs you have stored in the `NSUserDefaults` singleton, etc.  You can store the current version in `NSUserDefaults` and check to see if it matches the bundle's version id on startup, and use that test to determine what cleanup may be necessary before running the app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything its automatically replace old app with new one.